# How to calculate a value for multiple rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The problem is incentive and bonus amount is to be divided among a office may be a odd number, for example let Rs 100 will be divided as sales incentive for a office amoung 3 employees. In this case 2 employees will get 33 and 1 employee will get Rs 34, it does not matter who gets 33 or 34, the only thing matters is that the difference should be at minimum and the sum must not exceed than the allotted amount.
I came up with some basic functions to calculate the amount as
[image]

but the problem is  **how to loop through the employees/rows** ?

[image]

Comment: Where's the logic in Sales Incentive With OFC CD #1 is divided over 4 and OFC CD #2 over 3?

Comment: Good answer by Scott below.  Only thing I was going to add and its really dependent on how your data is really laid out, but I would give consideration to making the bonus values just another column of the sales table and avoid repeating your office code data.  Personal preference suggestion is all.

Comment: @P.b ofc cd 1 has 4 employees where as ofc cd 2 has only 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use for incentive:

```
 =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=COUNTIF(A:A,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,F:G,2,FALSE)-SUMIFS($C$1:C1,$A$1:A1,A2),ROUNDDOWN(VLOOKUP(A2,F:G,2,FALSE)/COUNTIF(A:A,A2),0))
```

I will let you do the Bonus as it is the same formula with a different lookup range in the two vlookups.

[image]

Comment: Damn you and your speedy accurate answers Cranner!  I had developed virtually the same answer while you were posting 8(  `=IF(COUNTIF($D$2:$D2,$D2)=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$8,$D2),VLOOKUP($D2,$J$3:$K$5,2,0)-SUMIF($D$1:$D1,$D2,$F$1:$F1),ROUNDDOWN(VLOOKUP($D2,$J$3:$K$5,2,0)/COUNTIF($D$2:$D$8,$D2),0))`

Comment: and fools seldom differ! 8)

Comment: @ScottCraner You are a genius !!! I thought the only way was VBA

Comment: @www.friend0.in it is just a matter of knowing what each formula returns and using tweak